# What is the difference between JobClient.java and JobSubmitter.java in hadoop2?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Which of these is used to submit job for execution in job tracker. It would be great if one can explain how both these classes are being used in different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1: JobClient**

**Job** control is done through the Job class in New API rather than the old class
***JobClient***

`Job` is job submitter's view of the Job.

It allows the user to configure the job, submit it, control its execution, and query the state. The set methods only work until the job is submitted, afterwards they will throw an IllegalStateException.

Normally the user creates the application, describes various facets of the job via Job and then submits the job and monitor its progress.

**Question** **2:** **JobSubmitter**

The `submit()` method on `Job` creates an internal `JobSubmitter` instance and calls `submitJobInternal()` on it.

Once the job is submitted the job,waitForCompletion() polls the job’s progress once per second and reports the progress to the console. When the `job` completes successfully, the job counters are displayed. Otherwise, the error that caused the job to fail is logged to the console.

The job submission process implemented by `JobSubmitter` does the following:

1. Asks the resource manager for a new application ID, used for the `MapReduce job ID`
2. Checks the output specification of the job. For example, if the output directory has not been specified or it already exists, the job is not submitted and an error is thrown to the `MapReduce` program.
3. Computes the `input splits` for the job. If the `splits` cannot be computed (because the input paths don’t exist, for example), the job is not submitted and an error is thrown to the `MapReduce` program.
4. Copies the resources needed to run the job, including the job JAR file, the
   configuration file, and the computed input splits, to the shared filesystem in a directory named after the job ID .
5. The job JAR is copied with a high replication factor (controlled by the mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication property, which defaults to 10) so that there are lots of copies across the cluster for the node managers to access when they run tasks for the job.
6. submits the job by calling `submitApplication()` on the resource manager

`Hadoop : The defiinitive guide foruth edition` is one of the best books to understand the concepts

From code end, you can refer to source code from grepcode :

[Job](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java/?v=source) : API to check : `waitForCompletion()` =>  `submit()` => `jobClient.submitJobInternal`

[JobClient](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java/?v=source) : `submitJobInternal`

Comment: Is it safe to say that all jobs are submitted through jobclient only and every job submission through job client will subsequently invoke jobsubmitter?

Comment: Replace JobClient (old Hadoop 1.x) with Job (Hadoop 2.x) and answer is yes.